# Facebook Graph API Insights Metric: Post demographic by gender age and country

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm able to get the gender/age and country breakdown of an authed user's fans for a Facebook page - but is it possible to get the same break down for impressions and/or consumptions **for a specific post** , like:

```
/{post-id}/insights/post_impressions //(then broken down by gender/age and countries?)
```

All I want is to look up a specific post and get the demographics of the people who engaged with it. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

try to download the owloo clone script from https://github.com/newbacknew/owloo.com. This is a base of scripts from owloo.com for get data from Facebook via the "ADS" Dashboard, also have to retrive analytics data from Twitter and Instagram.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer old questions.Try to add examples of code, not just a link to a repo or tutorial. We want to to have full answers on the site